# Insert field into an array of sub-documents. unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to insert a new field into each sub-document in every array of sub-documents. I have a semi-working script, expected result was `ordinal_number` to be inserted into each sub-document but it seems to be inserting into the first sub-document in each `comments` array in the collection.

```
db.posts.find({
"comments.ordinal_number":{"$exists":true}}).forEach(function(data){
   for(var i = 0; i < data.comments.length; i++) {
     db.posts.update(
    { 
         "_id": data._id, 
         "comments.body": data.comments[i].body
     },
     {
         "$set": {
           "comments.$.ordinal_number":
               1
         }
     },true,true
    );
  }
});
```

output result:

```
    "link" : "cxzdzjkztkqraoqlgcru",
        "author" : "machine",
        "title" : "arbitrary title",
        "comments" : [
            {
                "body" : "...",
                "email" : "ZoROirXN@thUNmWmY.com",
                "author" : "Foo bar",
                "ordinal_number" : 1
            },
            {
                "body" : "...",
                "email" : "eAYtQPfz@kVZCJnev.com",
                "author" : "Foo baz"
            }
]
```

Comment: @user3100115 I want to add an actual new field not update a field's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop the cursor and the array entries as well then use the [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)operator to update each sub-document in the array using ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) operations for maximum efficiency.

```js
var bulk = db.posts.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
db.posts.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    var nComments = doc.comments.length; 
    for (var i = 0; i < nComments; i++) {
        bulk.find( { 
            '_id': doc._id, 
            'comments': { '$elemMatch': { 'email': doc.comments[i]['email'] } }
        } ).update({
            '$set': { 'comments.$.ordinal_number': 1 } 
        }) 
    } 
    count++;
    if(count % 200 === 0) {   
        // Execute per 200 operations and re-init
        bulk.execute();     
        bulk = db.posts.initializeOrderedBulkOp(); 
     }
})

// Clean up queues.
if (count > 0)  bulk.execute();
```

Note that the Bulk API is new in 2.6 so if you are on older version you will need to use the [`.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) method.

```js
db.posts.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    var nComments = doc.comments.length; 
    for (var i = 0; i < nComments; i++) {
        db.posts.update( 
            { 
                '_id': doc._id, 
                 'comments': { '$elemMatch': { 'email': doc.comments[i]['email'] } }
            }, 

            { '$set': { 'comments.$.ordinal_number': 1 } }
         ) 
    } 
})
```